# Keyboard shortcuts to invoke and navigate help attached cell?

Tags: front-end, keyboard, cells

How to create a keyboard shortcut to invoke and navigate the small help attached cell with that contains the syntax templates and the link to the documentation?

Currently this help cell only shows up when you are at the end of a newly typed symbol for most symbols and can only be navigated with the mouse. I would like to be able to invoke it while the cursor is at the end or within any symbol and then to be able to navigate it with keystrokes instead of the mouse.

I suppose this is a `FrontEndToken` of some sort but I don't know where to being.

Comment: Afaict the tough part is to get a current position of the caret. You can always attach a cell in the center of a notebook if that is not an issue. I do this to the top right corner for [my live templates](https://github.com/kubaPod/DevTools/blob/master/DevTools/DevTools.m#L295).

Comment: You want an alternative to Ctrl+K? :)

Comment: @ihojnicki Yes, Ctrl+K brings up the auto complete attached cell.I am seeking to invoke the syntax templates and help attached cell with a keyboard shortcut and then navigate it with the keyboard instead of the mouse.  The small one with the double-down arrow and the information  icon.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+K will bring up the version with templates.

Comment: The up and down arrow keys can be used to navigate.

Comment: Doh!!  - For some reason this was not working.  Restart fixed it.  Thanks all.